# deployed appengine cloud endpoints 403

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My deployed site cant reference endpoints. It works perfectly locally but remotely I get a 403 in the client:

GET http://mailmanagerplus.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/agreement/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0 403 (Forbidden) rs=AItRSTOc4KBtnc5SIOEaPiMWPOclVYHqsA:153

All seems to have deployed successfully looking at the logs. I currently don't use  any authentication.

Any direction would be useful as I'm very new to this.

Comment: encountered the same problem here....did you have any idea yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to switch to "https" protocol if you want to use endpoints client library on the production.