# Google endpoints returns 403 forbidden when accessing from javascript

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

My deployed site cant reference endpoints from javascript. It works perfectly locally but remotely I get a 403 in the client:

GET http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/agreement/v1/rpc?fields=methods%2F*%2Fid&pp=0 403 (Forbidden) rs=AItRSTOc4KBtnc5SIOEaPiMWPOclVYHqsA:153

All seems to have deployed successfully looking at the logs. I currently don't use any authentication. I am accessing endpoints from javascript. I believe I need to access endpoints using https.

Any idea how can I configure javascript client to access endpoints using https.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what actually you were trying to do. Thanks

Comment: Implemented using endoints from javascript from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/calling-from-javascript It worked fine in local host. When deployed in production, I get 403 forbidden when page is loaded. Similar issue is discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430823/deployed-appengine-cloud-endpoints-403?rq=1 . I am not able to figure out how to use https from my javascript

Comment: Just write `https`, what's the problem. That is what the answer there says.